# What is the default pgpass.conf location for the user running PostgreSQL service on Windows 10?

Tags: windows, postgresql, windows-services, appdata

On Microsoft Windows, the pgpass file is located as followed:

> On Microsoft Windows the file is named %APPDATA%\postgresql\pgpass.conf (where %APPDATA% refers to the Application Data subdirectory in the user's profile).

source: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/libpq-pgpass.html

When I create a subscription, as shown below, I do not provided a password in the connection string.

```sql
CREATE SUBSCRIPTION alltables
CONNECTION 'host=192.168.1.5 port=5432 user=replicator1 dbname=test1'
PUBLICATION alltables;
```

Instead, I want the password to be stored in a `pgpass.conf` file with restricted access.

After a few tries, I have noticed that in the case of creating a subscription, the `pgpass.conf` is not expected to be found in the user directory of the Windows user running the `CREATE SUBSCRIPTION` command. In other words, if my Windows 10 user name is `foobar` the file is not expected to be `C:\Users\foobar\AppData\Roaming\postgresql\pgpass.conf`. Instead it seems to be expected in the user directory of the Windows user running the PostgreSQL program.

I have found this by adding `passfile=C:\\Users\\foobar\\AppData\\Roaming\\postgresql\\pgpass.conf` in the connection string and granting read permissions to the `NETWORK SERVICE` user (the user that runs the `postgres.exe` processes). In that case, the subscription is created. But if I remove the `passfile` option from the connection string then the terse `ERROR:  could not connect to the publisher: fe_sendauth: no password supplied` error message is returned.

So, where would `%APPDATA%\postgresql\pgpass.conf` point to in that case? Said differently, where should the `pgpass.conf` file be in that case?

Comment: That question essentially is: what is `%APPDATA%` for the `NETWORK SERVICE` user?

Comment: I suppose so, yes

Comment: One solution would be to run the Postgres service with a regular (restricted) user that does have an `%APPDATA%` directory. If you do that, you need to make sure to adjust the privileges on the current data directory so that the "new" user has full access to it.

Answer (score 3):

As commented by Laurenz, the question essentially is: what is `%APPDATA%` for the `NETWORK SERVICE` user?

In my case that is `C:\Windows\ServiceProfiles\NetworkService\AppData\Roaming\`.

So, by creating the pgpass file in `C:\Windows\ServiceProfiles\NetworkService\AppData\Roaming\postgresql\pgpass.conf`, I can create a subscription as below and the password will successfully be taken from the file.

```sql
CREATE SUBSCRIPTION alltables
CONNECTION 'host=192.168.1.5 port=5432 user=replicator1 dbname=test1'
PUBLICATION alltables;
```